# Is bookmarklets' execution enviroment same with browser console?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

For lacking experience of writing bookmarklets, I want to know that is the execution of JS code in bookmarklets like we run JS code in browser console(eg: firebug). Are there any differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, many consoles do have some extra tools in scope that you won't find in the global scope (where the bookmarklet is executed). Examples might be `keys` as a shortcut for `Object.keys` or `$` as a shortcut for `querySelectorAll`. Yet, I'm not really sure how these work; they might be more a kind of makro as well. For more information see [Firebug's *Command Line API* documentation](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API), also [Chrome Devtools Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console?hl=en) claims to support it and [Opera's Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/console/) at least supports a subset of it.

However, these are rare and you won't notice them usually, so writing your bookmarklet code in the console should work fine without distractions.